# How to find out if an XPages view(Panel) is sorted by a viewColumnHeader sort toggle switch?

Tags: xpages

I'm displaying a view using a viewPanel. The view contains some columns which are enabled to be sorted in both directions, which is working fine.

Now I'd need to find out if the view has been resorted by the user by being clicked on the "Sort Toggle" in the viewColumnHeader.
Is there a property or a method which I can access programmatically to find this out?
Or is there an event in the viewPanel I could intercept or listen to?

**Update:**
I found that the class UIViewColumnHeader (which is extended by XspViewColumnHeader) has some static properties describing the icons ([see here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/component/UIViewColumnHeader.html)) - could I check for them? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the help of those both sites, I solved resp. worked around my problem:

First, there was Naveen's solution how to [Getting ViewPanel Headers programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531352/getting-viewpanel-headers-programmatically)
Second, Mark Leusink's article about [the order of events in XPages](http://linqed.eu/?p=59).

This led me to following code:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var viewPnl:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1");
var list:java.util.List = viewPnl.getChildren();
var replaceRespCol = false;

for (var i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++) {
    var viewCol:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewColumn = list.get(i);
    var viewHdr:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewColumnHeader = viewCol.getHeader();

    if (@RightBack(viewHdr.getSortIcon(), "/") != "sort_none.gif") {
        replaceRespCol = true;
    }
}

if (getSearchKey() != "") {
    getComponent("viewColumn1").setRendered(false);
    getComponent("viewColumn1b").setRendered(true);
} else if (replaceRespCol == true) {
    getComponent("viewColumn1").setRendered(false);
    getComponent("viewColumn1b").setRendered(true);
} else {
    getComponent("viewColumn1").setRendered(true);
    getComponent("viewColumn1b").setRendered(false);
}}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

which enables me now to dynamically show a categorized column (viewColumn1)
- if no filter/search key is entered and
- no re-sort via the headers is done.
Otherwise, a flat column (viewColumn1b) is shown. HTH

Answer (score 2):

The sort column should be defined on the dominoView datasource in the sortColumn property, whose Java class is com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewData. That can be accessed by calling getData() on the ViewPanel

So you should be able to use getComponent("myViewPanel").getData().getSortColumn() in SSJS. By default I suspect it will be blank.

Comment: Dear Paul, thanks for the hint, but the "sortColumn" property already is set to a column of the backend view - this is working. I'd need to find out if the displayed view (which should be the panel) is re-sorted by one of the arrows in the column headers by the user.

Comment: I think that should still be the property to check. When the user clicks the arrow to sort a column, it has to change a property somewhere in order to affect the data you're seeing. It's not going to be on the backend NotesView class - that will not get changed or modified. I don't think it will be on the ViewPanel because that just handles display parameters for the e.g. 30 rows. It has to change the underlying dataset, which will be the dominoView datasource. Please check the sortColumn property. I think you'll find it gets changed. See http://www.intec.co.uk/understanding-xpages-views/

Comment: Ok, my page displays this information now in a computed field (which I refresh manually, as the re-sort only partially refreshes the viewPanel), but regardless of any re-sort I apply, the value stays at the data's specified sortColumn value...